Partition not being used for Ubuntu installation
I created a 150GB partition to install Ubuntu along side windows 11 as the dual boot OS. When I try to install the Ubuntu from USB I get "not enough storage"  error since it tries to install in the USB. I researched and found these this answer:
SSD not detected during Ubuntu installation
I have to change the RAID to AHCI but the issue is there is no SATA option in Pulse 17 B13V
in the BIos. I posted on the MSI platform but they aren't of much help and told me to ask ubuntu community.
I boot the ubuntu from the usb media and choose the try option after that I click the installer I get the error. I don't get the opportunity to chose the partition or "something else" option
What should I do?
Link to the platform post:https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?threads/where-is-the-sata-option-in-msi-pulse-17-b13v.402074/
edit
sudo parted -l
kingston dt 101 G2
disk: /dev/sda: 3918 MB

This question is similar to: How to use manual partitioning during installation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't get any option to chose the partition and I have only one ssd in my system

The option in the Ubuntu installer's "Installation type" screen  to start manual partitioning is called "Something else".

Also one other thing to note when I boot from usb everything is scaled so big. I tried changing the scale from the personalization but I am only able to reduce the size of icon

It's possible that the Ubuntu installer is in low graphics mode.

what is the possible solution? Should i make the bootable usb again because I created this one around 10 months ago and it has 22.04.1 LTS

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
